Political asylum and entreprise individuelle
We (my wife and I) are Ukrainian citizens, but we left Ukraine before the war started, since I found a job in Germany. We lived there with an EU Blue Card.
Then we decided to move to France since our daughter is here and I'm fluent in French. My German job contract is over, our blue Cards expired, and we wanted to create an entreprise individuelle.
At the préfecture I was told to first create the entreprise individuelle, then request a project viability statement from ANEF, and then they would give me a visa for entrepreneurship. I did all of that, but ANEF didn't want to give me their approval because I have no money in French banks, and to create an account in a French bank, I need a visa — the circle is closed. So in the end the préfecture refused to give me a visa.
Then, as we are Ukrainians and we have no other visa, we went to seek for asylum. So now I have a récépissé of asylum seeker and an entreprise individuelle where I cannot work because asylum seekers have no right to work in France.
Basically, my questions are:

Is it better to close the EI now?
If not, how can I get work permission for myself after half a year? Because the law states that an asylum seeker can ask for work permit after half a year, but the work permit must be queried by (and given to) the employer. But in my case I'm the employer for myself, and googling gave me no results.


This reads like a very particular set of circumstances, the resolution of which would benefit from advice from a qualified immigration lawyer.
